# NServiceBus/MVC injection - Autofac doesn't like IControllerFactory?

Tags: model-view-controller, dependency-injection, nservicebus, autofac

all.  I am getting started with NServiceBus and have a pretty good handle on the basics thanks to Pluralsight and the internet.  I have an stock MVC 4 project and I have setup dependency injection for my controllers (thanks to [this blog post](http://www.make-awesome.com/2011/02/injecting-nservicebus-into-asp-net-mvc-3/)).

Here is how I have my bus setup in Global.asax:

```
_bus = Configure.With()
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .ForMVC()
                .Log4Net()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .MsmqTransport()
                .UnicastBus()
                .SendOnly();
```

I am assigning it to a local private variable because I need access to the bus in Global so I can do some stuff on Session_End.  However, when I run, I get the following error:

> The requested service 'System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory' has not been
>   registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to
>   provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.

According to my stack trace, the failure point is when Autofac tries to resolve the type.  For the sake of sanity, I removed the private variable and used just the Configure statement, same thing.  I also have Ninject wired up in this app because that is my IoC of choice.  Thinking that it was interfering with Autofac in some way, I removed Ninject from the equation, still not working.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?  Am I missing something?  This is my first time with NServiceBus, but from everything I've seen, this should just work.  Any info would be super helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at our MVC4 sample (this is running against v4, the next major release):
https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/develop/Samples/Messaging.Msmq/MyWebClient

Comment: Thanks, John.  I will fork that repo this weekend, possibly tomorrow and take a look, see what is different.  Any idea when v4 is coming out?  More curious than anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from your code, John!  Here was my issue.  This is what I had in my Dependency Resolver Adapter:

```
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    _builder.Build(serviceType);
}
```

What I needed to do was what you did in your MVC4 example:

```
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    return (Configure.Instance.Configurer.HasComponent(serviceType)) ? _builder.Build(serviceType) : null;
}
```

Once I did that, it all sorted itself out.  Thanks again for the help!